# unix read command with special charecters

Tags: unix

I am writing a shell script which will read a user input and do some processing

> ```
> echo "Enter your query \n"
> read query
> echo $query > temp
> ```

I am facing an issue when i enter any special characters. For example if i enter

> ```
> select * from temp;
> ```

the `*` in the select statement is getting converted into all the file names in the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotation marks to prevent looking in the file system:

```
echo "$query" > temp
```